# Terminology: Alternatives for zero crossing

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

Is it correct to name the red and blue points hinge points, as an alternative to zero crossing? Or are their better terms to describe these points?

[image: zero crossings]

---

**Update**

I have several functions like these. I want to stress that these points are 'fixed', and not the fact they cross zero.

[image: updated zero crossing]

Comment: Points $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$ are called zeros of $f$, or roots of $f = 0$ or the $0$-level set of $f$. Haven't heard of hinge points

Comment: It sounds like "hinge points" might be another name for what I know as "turning points", which are where $f''(x)=0$. In the graphic above, it looks like the red and blue points are turning points and zeroes.

Comment: Zero crossing seems like a perfectly adequate term (even preferred I would say). Is there any reason you don't want to use it?

Comment: Turning point is another term for inflection point.

Comment: I suggest "pivot point". Which I suppose means the same as hinge point, but it sounds more technical :-)

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is a real or complex valued function and $x$ is the point for which $f(x) = 0$, the usual terminology is to say that $x$ is the *root* of $f$.

Comment: I updated to question to clarify what I exactly mean.

Comment: @traindriver You made it less clear, actually.